# Where is it treated as an int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I've seen answers to similar questions but I can't find the place in my code where I'm treating x as an int.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def aitken(x,y,value,n):
    if n == 1:
        return y[0]
    first_array = x.pop(n-1)
    second_array = x.pop(n-2)
    first_y = y.pop(n-1)
    second_y = y.pop(n-2)
    n1 = n-1
    return (aitken(first_array,first_y,value,n1)*(value - x[n-1]) - aitken(second_array, second_y,value,n1)*(value - x[n-2]))/(x[n-1] - x[n-2])

x = [1, 4, 7, 11, 15, 20, 30, 50, 77, 92, 100]
y = [5, 20, 52, 121, 228, 403, 903, 2504, 5929, 8464, 10005]
n = len(x)
x_fit = np.arange(0,104,1)
y_fit = aitken(x,y,x_fit,n)
```

Here's the error messages:

```
  File "exl.py", line 17, in <module>
    y_fit = aitken(x,y,x_fit,n)
  File "exl.py", line 13, in aitken
    return (aitken(first_array,first_y,value,n1)*(value - x[n-1]) - aitken(second_array, second_y,value,n1)*(value - x[n
-2]))/(x[n-1] - x[n-2])
  File "exl.py", line 8, in aitken
    first_array = x.pop(n-1)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Sorry if this question is too basic. I'm new to python.

Comment: `first_array` is a *value* extracted from `x`, but is then passed to the recursive call **as** `x`, which is presumably wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, please make a [mre].

Comment: Oh so its a value? How do I construct two arrays from x then?

Comment: are you expecting `first_array` to be a list? what should cantain?

Comment: Nevermind, got it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable first_array is an int because it's one element of your list x (which are all ints). You'd find it easier to debug if you didn't use the same names for function arguments as the variables in the main script.

Answer (score 1):

Once the function reach the return value, you passed to it first_array, which you think is a list.

first_array is an integer since the pop function returns:

The last value or the given index value from the list.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is because you are no longer passing an array into your function when you recursively call it.

```
    first_array = x.pop(n-1)
    second_array = x.pop(n-2)
```

This is not giving you an array, but rather the value at location (n-1). For example:

```
x = [1, 4, 7, 11, 15, 20, 30, 50, 77, 92, 100]
first_array = x.pop(n-1)
# first_array = 100
# x = [1, 4, 7, 11, 15, 20, 30, 50, 77, 92]
```

So when you pass first_array in and try to pop x it is no longer an array and an error is being thrown. Instead you will want to modify your return so instead of passing a scalar back in you are passing an array. I hope this helps, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what is expected if you use pop method whith a list:

```
x=[1,2,3]
f_array=x.pop(0)
print(f_array)
```

Output:

```
1
```

So it is not a list,so you get an error,
because you can't reapply pop on this variable, which in this case is an integer because the deleted list item is an integer